# Einstein notation and writing down the geodesic equation - a misunderstanding?

Tags: general-relativity, differential-geometry, conventions, notation

if one wants to write down the geodesic equation to describe the movement of the planets (for i=1 in the following context) one uses the metric tensor $g_{ik}$ for spherical symmetric coordinates.

One then goes on by calculating the Christoffel symbols according to

$$\Gamma^i_{kl}=\frac{1}{2}g^{im}\left(g_{mk,l}+g_{ml,k}-g_{kl,m}\right)$$

My question now is:

I've learned that if there is some expression written down by using Einstein notation, one must sum over the variable from 0 to 3 iff the variable is a greek letter (e.g. $\nu, \mu$). Iff the variable is a normal letter (e.g. $k,l$) one must sum from 1 to 3. Does this then mean that in calculating the Christoffel  symbols for the geodesic equation, one is not required to calculate $\Gamma^0_{00}$ for example because this would be $k=l=0$? On the other hand this seems odd to me...

Comment: No, this Greek/Latin distinction is not universal. The indices on the Christoffel symbols do run from 0 to 3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Einstein summation convention posits that if an index label appears both in an "up" and a "down" position, it should be summed over. This part of the convention is more or less unambiguous. It does happen sometimes that you repeat indices and you do *not* want to sum, but then you should put a note next to your equations.

Now to the much less unified convention of Greek/Latin label naming. Yes, many people use the *convention* that Latin characters from the second half of the alphabet ($i,j,k,l,m,...$) mean "spatial components" ($1,2,3$), whereas $\mu,\nu$ correspond to the full range of space-time components $0,1,2,3$. However, this is *not* unified! For example, a very common alternative is to use small Latin characters from the beginning of the alphabet ($a,b,c,d,...$) to denote the full range of space-time components.

Now, in the example you give, the index $m$ must run through the full available range of components available on the manifold (which I assume is $0,1,2,3$ if you are on a 4D manifold), otherwise the expression is simply not valid in general. (However, your context may be special, such as that all $g^{0\mu}$ components of the metric vanish.)